# are the past outcomes relevant in calculating future odds.

Tags: stochastic-processes, dice

If I rolled a dice and got on a $6$ the chance of that was obviously $1/6$.
So if I now roll again, will my chance of rolling another 6 be again 1/6 or $1/36$?

Another example, lets say I rolled yesterday $100$ times a $6$ in a row the odds of that would have been $1,5306467074865063414445284410446\times 10^{-78}$.

So if i then go to bed wake the next day up and wanna role a 6 are the odds gonna be for that throw $1/6$, or $1,5306467074865063414445284410446\times 10^{-78}$ times $1/6$ ?

Thanks for anyone who responds :)

Comment: Assuming of course that the die is fair, it is normally assumed that rolls are independent and therefore the probability that the second roll is  $6$ is $1/6$. The probability that *both* the first and the second rolls are $6$ is $1/36$.

Comment: so what if i rolled a 6 yesterday. and i sit now infront of the dice and want to roll another 6. will the odds be reset to 1/6 or will it be 1/36. 

or lets say i won yesterday the lottery and the odds for that were 1 in a million.
And i go today to the lottery again will the odds to win be again back to 1 in a million , or will it be 1 in a trillion.
(story:bcs my friend is saying you only have to multiply the odds if you didnt roll yet and you wanna know what they are for winning twice in a row. but if you already won and want to win again the odds will be reset, and not multiplied.) ty

Answer (score 1):

The events are independent - meaning they do not affect one another.

The word that's key here is "*both*", just as @user1001001 pointed out. Let's say I flip a coin $3$ times consecutively. What are the possible outcomes? ${HHH}$, ${HHT}$, ${THT}$... etc etc. How many possible outcomes are there? Well, it's

$${2\times 2\times 2=8}$$

There's $8$ possible outcomes. But only $1$ out of these $8$ outcomes is a sequence where I simply get three heads (${HHH}$). So the probability of getting **all three** as heads consecutively is "$1$ out of $8$" = ${\frac{1}{8}}$.

We can actually show that we have no predictive power. We can use the formula

$${P(\text{A given B})=\frac{P(\text{A and B})}{P(\text{A})}}$$

If you replace ${A}$ with "the third toss being heads" and ${B}$ with "the first two tosses were heads" you end up with

$${P(\text{the last toss is heads GIVEN the first two were heads})}$$

$${=\frac{P(\text{the last toss is heads and the first two tosses were heads})}{P(\text{the first two tosses were heads})}=\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}}$$

In other words - just because you got two heads to begin with, the chance of you getting another heads is still ${\frac{1}{2}}$.

The point to take away is context. If we are looking at the overall situation (the three tosses as a sequence ${THT}$ etc) the probability of getting the sequence ${HHH}$ is low. But even though this is the case - it doesn't allow you to predict **at runtime** what will happen, no matter how counter-intuitive it may seem, since if you've already gotten two heads for example - the event has already happened. Since the flips are independent, it still is not going to affect your chances on the last coin flip being heads of ${\frac{1}{2}}$. The "unlikely" part of the sequence has already occurred. Hope this helps.

Comment: so what if i rolled a 6 yesterday. and i sit now infront of the dice and want to roll another 6. will the odds be reset to 1/6 or will it be 1/36. or lets say i won yesterday the lottery and the odds for that were 1 in a million. And i go today to the lottery again will the odds to win be again back to 1 in a million like first time, or will it be 1 in a trillion. (bcs my friend is saying you only have to multiply the odds if you didnt roll yet and you wanna know what they are for winning twice in a row. but if you already won and want to win again the odds will be reset, and not multiplied.

Comment: @ZYNKAzockt your friend is correct. It's admittedly counter-intuitive - but the key point is **the event already happened** and **the events are independent**. If the question is "what are the odds I win the lottery twice in a row?" the answer is 1 in a trillion. If the question is "I won the lottery yesterday, what is the chance I win again today?" the answer is (provided the lottery company don't get upset with you trying again and mess with the results) 1 in a million

Comment: @ZYNKAzockt It's counter-intuitive because you expect that the fact you won already should somehow give you less chance of winning again (because we know the chances of winning twice in a row are low) - but this *is not* how this works. Provided the two events are independent (i.e. winning once doesn't affect your ability to win again and you are given the exact same chance as last time) - the probability does not change. This is because the event has already happened - **you already know the result**.

Comment: @ZYNKAzockt I have edited my answer also to add this small bit at the end

Comment: thats so hard to accept tho, bcs for example if you roll a dice 6million times and it was all the time a 6.and then you sit down for the 6thmillions time +1 and want to roll a 6 again the odds for your 6,000,001 throw of 6ses in a row will be 1/6 is just so hard to accept.
ty for your response tho i understand it now.thanks rly much.

Comment: @ZYNKAzockt Oh for sure yeah, I can see why if you aren't trained in conditional probability (which is the category this problem falls under) this does seem extremely strange. But the point you should hang onto is that if we roll the dice $6$ million times and got 6's each time - **you know the result** of those $6$ million throws. If you throw the dice one more time after that (so you do $6$ million ${+1}$ throws overall) - the chance of that being a $6$ is simply ${\frac{1}{6}}$. You already know the result of the previous throws, and the throws don't affect each other :)

Comment: @ZYNKAzockt Just note though that if the throws did somehow affect each other (for example, maybe the dice get's significantly worn down and becomes a bit "weighted" over the throws?) then the probability will not be ${\frac{1}{6}}$, since the events are no longer independent :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you claim it is a fair die the chance of a $6$ is $\frac 16$ regardless of the history.  Period.  **End.**  If you roll $100$ sixes in a row maybe you doubt the assertion that it is a fair die.  That would make your first statement false-it is not true that the chance of a $6$ is $\frac 16$.  There are a number of unfair dice in the world.  Maybe you have found one.  In that case the odds are quite high that the next roll will be a $6$ as well.  The exact number is difficult to calculate as it depends on your assessment of the population of dice you may be using, but that is not important.